# parametrized terraform template

Tags: templates, cloud, openstack, terraform

I have a terraform project to create a 99 virtual machines in Openstack i can not use cloud-init and i must modify the hostname of every machine

**hostname.tplt :**

```
sudo sed -i -e "s/debian[7-9]/${host_name}/g" /etc/hostname
sudo invoke-rc.d hostname.sh start

sudo sed -i -e "s/127\.0\.1\.1.*/127.0.1.1\t${host_name}.${domain_name} ${host_name}/g" /etc/hosts
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y install dbus && sudo hostnamectl set-hostname ${host_name}
```

**part of main.tf :**

```
data "template_file" "hostname_servers" {
  template = "${file("templates/hostname.tplt")}"

  vars {
    host_name   = "${format("%s-proxy-%02d", var.prefix_name, count.index+1)}"
    domain_name = "${var.domain_name}"
  }
}
```

*Ressource*

```
resource "openstack_compute_instance_v2" "proxy-instance" {
  count       = "${var.count_proxy}"
  name        = "${format("%s-proxy-%02d", var.prefix_name, count.index+1)}"
  image_name  = "${var.image}"
  flavor_name = "${var.flavor_proxy}"

  network {
    name = "${format("%s-%s", var.prefix_name, var.network_name)}"
  }

  connection {
    user = "${var.user}"
  }

  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
      "${data.template_file.hostname_servers.rendered}"
    ]
  }
}
```

**the use case :**
when i start a terraform plan it works for the proxy-instance resource but i need to do that for the 99 machines,
i don't like to duplicate the templates data 99 times,
and i don't know how to parammetrize the template to be able to apply for all the machines
any idea ?

Comment: What should your hostnames look like? Are they all different or do they follow a pattern such as `host-1.example.com`?

Comment: the hoste name is the name of resource i update my question   host_name   = "${format("%s-proxy-%02d", var.prefix_name, count.index+1)}"

Comment: So what's wrong with what you currently have? That looks like it will work fine for up to 99 machines

Comment: i don't like to duplicate the (data template for 99 times)
data "template_file" "hostname_servers" {
  template = "${file("templates/hostname.tplt")}"

  vars {
    host_name   = "${format("%s-proxy-%02d", var.prefix_name, count.index+1)}"
    domain_name = "${var.domain_name}"
  }
}

Comment: i'd like to have the name of instance = hostname for evry machine

Comment: What makes you think you have to? At a glance that looks dynamic to me

Comment: I need to overload the [ data "template_file" "hostname] which allows me to overload "host_name" variable inside every "resource" openstack_compute_instance_v2 "

Answer (score 0):

If you set `count` to the same value on multiple resources then you can use `count.index` to create correspondences between the instances of one block and the instances of another, like this:

```
data "template_file" "hostname_servers" {
  count = "${var.count_proxy}"

  template = "${file("templates/hostname.tplt")}"

  vars {
    host_name   = "${format("%s-proxy-%02d", var.prefix_name, count.index+1)}"
    domain_name = "${var.domain_name}"
  }
}

resource "openstack_compute_instance_v2" "proxy-instance" {
  count = "${var.count_proxy}"

  name        = "${format("%s-proxy-%02d", var.prefix_name, count.index+1)}"
  image_name  = "${var.image}"
  flavor_name = "${var.flavor_proxy}"

  network {
    name = "${format("%s-%s", var.prefix_name, var.network_name)}"
  }

  connection {
    user = "${var.user}"
  }

  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
      # use count.index to match the template instance corresponding
      # to this compute instance instance.
      "${data.template_file.hostname_servers.*.rendered[count.index]}"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: every resource has a specific name so with your solution i will have the same name of all my machines

Comment: The `count.index` references are intended to ensure that each server gets a different hostname.